# Add hours to javascript date object bug?

Tags: javascript, date, actionscript

Hi guys so I've a wierd bug that I can't figure out. I create a date object from a date chooser and a set of combos with hours/mins.

Now the problem is when it's March 30th 2013 and 1pm adding 12 hours only adds 11 for some reason.  With any other day like March 31st 2013 at 1pm this is fine.  See example below

```
var d = new Date(1364601600000)
d.setHours(13)
d.setMinutes(13)

console.log(d)

d.setHours(d.getHours() + 12)

console.log(d)

console.log('--')

var d2 = new Date(1364688000000)
d2.setHours(13)
d2.setMinutes(13)

console.log(d2)

d2.setHours(d2.getHours() + 12)

console.log(d2)
```

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8L2W/2/

Comment: Works fine for me. `Sat Mar 30 2013 13:13:00 GMT+0530` (1 PM), and adding 12 to it, `Sun Mar 31 2013 01:13:00 GMT+0530` (1 AM).

Comment: What do you get in the fiddle? I get 4 outputs:  

`Sat Mar 30 2013 13:13:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Sun Mar 31 2013 00:13:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
--
Sun Mar 31 2013 13:13:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Mon Apr 01 2013 01:13:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`:  

 and the second time is wrong.

Comment: You can see that it is the Daylight scheme that is making the difference. GMT Standard Time does not add extra hour while GMT Daylight adds 1 hour

Comment: Thanks man, that explains alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The daylight scheme for the year 2013 works as follows :

```
Sunday, 31 March 2013, 01:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
Sunday, 31 March 2013, 02:00:00 local daylight time instead
```

For reference, please check [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136&year=2013)